# Can I profile my .zshrc/.zshenv?

Tags: profiling, zsh

It seems like my shell is taking *way* too long to start up.  Is there any way to profile it so I can figure out what's slowing it down so much?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try adding this at the beginning of the file:

```
# set the trace prompt to include seconds, nanoseconds, script name and line number
# This is GNU date syntax; by default Macs ship with the BSD date program, which isn't compatible
PS4='+$(date "+%s:%N") %N:%i> '
# save file stderr to file descriptor 3 and redirect stderr (including trace 
# output) to a file with the script's PID as an extension
exec 3>&2 2>/tmp/startlog.$$
# set options to turn on tracing and expansion of commands contained in the prompt
setopt xtrace prompt_subst
```

and this at the end:

```
# turn off tracing
unsetopt xtrace
# restore stderr to the value saved in FD 3
exec 2>&3 3>&-
```

And you should get a detailed log showing the epoch_second.nanosecond time of the execution of each line. Note that GNU `date` (and OS support) is required to have nanosecond output.

Edit:

added comments

Edit 2:

If you have zsh 4.3.12 or later, you should be able to set `PS4` like this instead of using the `date` command:

```
zmodload zsh/datetime
setopt promptsubst
PS4='+$EPOCHREALTIME %N:%i> '
```

which should work on both Linux and OS X to give you nanosecond precision.

Comment: I added a very important space to what I originally posted.

Comment: Make sure to `setopt prompt_subst`, too - otherwise the `$(date ..)` part won't get substituted.

Comment: Could you please add some more notes on what each line above is doing exactly?

Comment: I wrote [a blog post about zsh profiling](https://esham.io/2018/02/zsh-profiling). It includes a zsh script that turns the log into a sorted list of which commands take the most time. (I used EPOCHREALTIME and XTRACE like you suggested—thank you for writing this answer!)

Comment: You no longer need to load that module. I'm not sure what version allows it, but you can do `%D{%s%.}` in place of `$EPOCHREALTIME`

Answer (score 3):

Zsh has a profiling module. At the beginning of `~/.zshrc` or `~/.zshenv` add it like:

```
# Uncomment to use the profiling module
# zmodload zsh/zprof
```

Uncomment it, start a new interactive shell then run the command `zprof`. You will get a detailed list of items you can review to better understand where your performance bottlenecks are:

```
num  calls                time                       self            name
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1)    1           7.29     7.29   19.60%      7.29     7.29   19.60%  _p9k_init_ssh
 2)    2           6.72     3.36   18.06%      6.63     3.31   17.81%  gitstatus_start_impl
 3)    1           4.00     4.00   10.75%      4.00     4.00   10.75%  _p9k_must_init
 4)    3          19.28     6.43   51.80%      3.82     1.27   10.28%  (anon)
 5)    1           1.63     1.63    4.37%      1.63     1.63    4.37%  _p9k_restore_state_impl
 6)    1          16.92    16.92   45.46%      1.61     1.61    4.32%  _p9k_precmd_impl
 7)    1           7.13     7.13   19.16%      0.87     0.87    2.33%  _p9k_set_prompt
 8)   22           6.26     0.28   16.83%      0.84     0.04    2.27%  _p9k_build_segment
 9)   17           0.82     0.05    2.19%      0.82     0.05    2.19%  _p9k_param
10)    6           2.24     0.37    6.02%      0.74     0.12    1.98%  _p9k_left_prompt_segment
11)    5           0.59     0.12    1.60%      0.59     0.12    1.60%  add-zsh-hook
12)    1           3.05     3.05    8.20%      0.58     0.58    1.56%  prompt_dir
```

And here's a one-liner from [speeding up zsh](https://carlosbecker.com/posts/speeding-up-zsh/) you'll appreciate if start time feels sporadic:

```
for i in $(seq 1 10); do /usr/bin/time zsh -i -c exit; done
```

Run that job and you should see output like:

```
        0.05 real         0.02 user         0.02 sys
        0.05 real         0.02 user         0.02 sys
        0.05 real         0.02 user         0.02 sys
        0.05 real         0.02 user         0.02 sys
        0.05 real         0.02 user         0.02 sys
        0.05 real         0.02 user         0.02 sys
        0.05 real         0.02 user         0.02 sys
        0.05 real         0.02 user         0.02 sys
        0.05 real         0.02 user         0.02 sys
        0.05 real         0.02 user         0.02 sys
```

Profit.

Answer (score 2):

You can start your timer at the first suspicious point in your `~/.zshrc` (or at the beginning):

```
integer t0=$(date '+%s')  # move this around
... maybe something suspect ...

# End of zshrc
function {
    local -i t1 startup
    t1=$(date '+%s')
    startup=$(( t1 - t0 ))
    [[ $startup -gt 1 ]] && print "Hmm, poor shell startup time: $startup"
}
unset t0
```

This alerts me if ever I see a too-slow startup, and I leave it in as a permanent wrapper.

For more sophisticated measurements, **there is a zsh module called `zprof`**. It's as simple as temporarily wrapping the contents of your `~/.zshrc` in a `zmodload zsh/zprof` and `zprof`. This will dump some verbose profiling tables that are easy enough to interpret.

More info in `zshmodules(1)` manpage.

When I find things that are particularly slow (rbenv init, vcs_info check-for-changes, antigen, nvm, zsh-mime-setup, interpreter version checking, etc) I **add `SLOW` comments as reminders**, and try to find workarounds. Slow startups can cause a lot grief, so I tend to avoid zsh packages/framewords whose inner workings I don't grok. compinit is the slowest thing I'm willing to live with and is ~half of total startup time.