# ZSH: How to time a block of code?

Tags: bash, zsh

In bash I am able to write a script that contains something like this:

```
{ time {

#series of commands
echo "something"
echo "another command"
echo "blah blah blah"

} } 2> $LOGFILE
```

In ZSH the equivalent code does not work and I can not figure out how to make it work for me.  This code works but I don't exactly know how to get it to wrap multiple commands.

```
{ time echo "something" } 2>&1
```

I know I can create a new script and put the commands in there then time the execution properly, but is there a way to do it either using functions or a similar method to the bash above?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try the following instead:

```
{ time ( echo hello ; sleep 10s;  echo hola ; ) } 2>&1
```

Comment: You have made my day just that much better.  Works as advertised.

Answer (score 16):

If you want to profile your code you have a few alternatives:

- Time subshell execution like:

  `time ( commands ... )`
- Use REPORTTIME to check for slow commands:

  `export REPORTTIME=3 # display commands with execution time >= 3 seconds`
- `setop xtrace` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351244/can-i-profile-my-zshrc-zshenv)
- The [zprof](http://stderr.org/doc/zsh-doc/html/zsh_22.html#SEC205) module

Comment: `REPORTTIME` is great for tasks that have taken an unexpectedly long amount of time to run, as you don't have to remember to time it before you start it. It displays the time taken in the same format as `time`, so is probably using `time` on every command but only showing the output if the execution time is greater than `REPORTTIME`.

Answer (score 2):

Try replace { with ( ?
I think this should help

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `times` POSIX shell builtin in conjunction with functions.
It will report the user and system time used by the shell and its children. See
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/times.html

Example:

```
somefunc() {
    code you want to time here
    times
}
```

The reason for using a shell function is that it creates a new shell context, at the start of which `times` is all zeros (try it). Otherwise the result contains the contribution of the current shell as well. If that is what you want, forget about the function and put `times` last in your script.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in zsh. The functions don't introduce new contexts there.