# How can you get zsh's REPORTTIME variable to print the command that ran?

Tags: profiling, zsh

[Setting the `$REPORTTIME` variable in zsh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6693784/329700) will cause zsh to print the time of commands that run for longer than the value of the environment variable.

However *all* you get is the time, when I set it in my .zshrc I got:

```
  0.00s user 0.00s system 25% cpu 0.001 total
  0.00s user 0.00s system 75% cpu 0.003 total
  0.00s user 0.00s system 30% cpu 0.002 total
  0.00s user 0.00s system 77% cpu 0.003 total
  0.00s user 0.00s system 34% cpu 0.001 total
  0.00s user 0.00s system 87% cpu 0.003 total
  0.00s user 0.00s system 48% cpu 0.001 total
  0.00s user 0.00s system 86% cpu 0.002 total
  0.00s user 0.01s system 88% cpu 0.014 total
  0.00s user 0.00s system 11% cpu 0.014 total
  0.00s user 0.01s system 85% cpu 0.016 total
  0.00s user 0.00s system 20% cpu 0.016 total
  0.00s user 0.00s system 82% cpu 0.007 total
```

This isn't too helpful as it doesn't tell you *what* is being slow. Is there a way to also print the command that caused `$REPORTTIME` to trigger?

Comment: The command name is output in the time line when the command has been run directly, but not when it has been run from a function (same problem with the `time` builtin, this is not specific to `REPORTTIME`). I suppose that it is a bug in zsh.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setopt xtrace` to have each command printed before it is executed. Combined with `REPORTTIME`, this should give you the information you need. You need to put `setopt xtrace` *inside* the script(s) you want to monitor.

For example, take this shell script named `test`:

```
#!/bin/zsh
setopt xtrace
ls foo
ls bar
ls baz
unsetopt xtrace
```

Running the script (with `REPORTTIME` set) results in:

```
% ./test
+./test:3> ls foo
ls: cannot access foo: No such file or directory
  0.00s user 0.00s system 2% cpu 0.154 total
+./test:4> ls bar
ls: cannot access bar: No such file or directory
  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 0.005 total
+./test:5> ls baz
ls: cannot access baz: No such file or directory
  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 0.008 total
+./test:6> unsetopt xtrace
./test  0.01s user 0.00s system 1% cpu 0.758 total
```