# Bash loop taking hours to loop after about waiting a few hours between each run

Tags: bash

#### Description

Hello,

I have a bash script which loops through certain commands by finding them in `/usr/local/bin/` and execute them. The commands give an output which are just numbers and we take these numbers, store them in a file and compare the current outputs with the outputs that are stored in the file if the time difference between them are more than half an hour. If not, then simply don't compare and just print the recent numbers.

Here's my script;

```sh
#!/bin/bash

warning="\e[93m%-17s%-12s%-12s\n"
danger="\e[91m%-17s%-12s%-12s\n"
green="\e[92m%-17s%-12s%-12s\n"
normal="%-17s%-12s%-12s\n"

wallets=/usr/local/bin/*-cli

current_date=$(date +%s)

for i in $wallets; do
    current_blocks=`$i getblockcount`
    coin_name=`basename $i -cli`

    if [ ! "$line" ]; then
        read line
        set -- $line
    fi

    if [ "$1" == "$coin_name" ]; then
        line='' # read new line next time
        time_difference=$(( $current_date - $3 ))

            if (( time_difference > 3600 )); then
                if (( current_blocks > $2 )); then
                    printf "$green" $coin_name $current_blocks $2
                    sed -i '' "/$1/c$1 $current_blocks $current_date" blocks.log
                    tput sgr0
                else
                    printf "$danger" $coin_name $current_blocks $2
                    sleep 2
                    tput sgr0
                fi
            elif (( time_difference > 1800 )); then
                if (( current_blocks > $2 )); then
                    printf "$green" $coin_name $current_blocks $2
                    sed -i '' "/$1/c$1 $current_blocks $current_date" blocks.log
                    tput sgr0
                else
                    printf "$warning" $coin_name $current_blocks $2
                    sleep 2
                    tput sgr0
                fi
            else
                printf "$normal" $coin_name $current_blocks $2
                tput sgr0
            fi

    else
            # $line as well as $1 and $2 remain set, will be used in next loop cycle
            if [ ! "$1" ]; then         # $1 is empty at EOF
                # create a new blocks.log to not disturb reading from original:
                cp blocks.log $$; mv $$ blocks.log
                echo "$coin_name $current_blocks $current_date" >>blocks.log
            else
                # insert before current line (address /$1/)
                sed -i '' "/$1/i$coin_name $current_blocks $current_date" blocks.log
            fi
    fi

done <blocks.log
```

And here's a sample output of the `blocks.log` file;

```sh
# first one is the $coin_name second one is $current_blocks and the third one is unix time.
bitcoin 99983 1550742031
litecoin 138432 1550742031
dash 130994 1550742031
```

When you run the script, it both displays a similar output as the `blocks.log` file and also modify them in the `blocks.log` file depending on the `if-else` conditions in the script.

#### The problem

The problem with this script is that when I run it for the first few times, it's working just fine and almost instant to loop through however as I run the script more and more or just run it for a few times and then wait for about 5-6 hours then run the script again, it takes almost hours to loop through which should be instant considering the fact that there are only a few `$wallets` and they give you the output instantly as you run the `$i getblockcount` command so I don't know why it's taking hours to run the script after a while.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You are reading and writing the file`blocks.log` at the same time – this can't be healthy. Not sure if that's the problem, but you should definitively fix it. You might also want to take a look at https://www.shellcheck.net/.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. I don't know how to make it other way rather than reading and writing at the same time tho.

Comment: 1. Compute the new values and write them to variable or a temporary file. 2. At the end, overwrite the old file with the new one.

Comment: @Socowi do you mind answering this question with an example script? I'm sorry I'm new to bash so..

Comment: @MarryJane Is this on your machine or is whatever this runs on also used in development? could things have been installed like `awscli` or something?

Comment: @Benbentwo I'm just running this script on a $10 DigitalOcean server with Ubuntu 16.04 and that's where I will be running this script forever. So I guess I can install `awscli`?

Comment: Ah sorry no, dont need to install that! thats command line tools for aws. I just thought `/usr/local/bin/*-cli` might have other things that are scanned. I'm now realizing `awscli` doesn't match `*-cli`

Comment: Does it help when you replace `done <blocks.log` with `done` ?

Comment: It is necessary to have it so I can read it while running the script to compare the data at the same time. @WalterA

Comment: You are already reading from and writing to the file inside the loop.The for-loop uses `$wallets`, it is unclear for me what happens with the `<blocks.log`.
The `cp blocks.log $$; mv $$ blocks.log` might cause problems, maybe when it has a certain size (and that might be an explanation why it seems to run fine the first few times and will hang later).

Comment: Put `set -x` in line 2 of the script. This will show the commands when they are executed and we can see which commands take that long.

Comment: Your _sample output of the `blocks.log` file_ is implausible, since the script keeps the names sorted.

Comment: @Armali looks like it wasn't hanging. I find out that the script was exiting because of in some part, one of the `$2`s getting deleted. It just randomly deletes so I guess there's a conflict happening because of the reading/writing at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure by reading it exactly but, one thing you could look into is the `time` command, `man time` for description.

```
warning="\e[93m%-17s%-12s%-12s\n"
danger="\e[91m%-17s%-12s%-12s\n"
green="\e[92m%-17s%-12s%-12s\n"
normal="%-17s%-12s%-12s\n"

wallets=/usr/local/bin/*-cli

current_date=$(date +%s)

for i in $wallets; do

{ time (
    current_blocks=`$i getblockcount`
    coin_name=`basename $i -cli`

    { time (
    if [ ! "$line" ]; then
        read line
        set -- $line
    fi
    ) } > wallet-$i-lineread.log 2>&1 

    if [ "$1" == "$coin_name" ]; then
        line='' # read new line next time
        time_difference=$(( $current_date - $3 ))

            if (( time_difference > 3600 )); then
                if (( current_blocks > $2 )); then
                    printf "$green" $coin_name $current_blocks $2
                    sed -i '' "/$1/c$1 $current_blocks $current_date" blocks.log
                    tput sgr0
                else
                    printf "$danger" $coin_name $current_blocks $2
                    sleep 2
                    tput sgr0
                fi
            elif (( time_difference > 1800 )); then
                if (( current_blocks > $2 )); then
                    printf "$green" $coin_name $current_blocks $2
                    sed -i '' "/$1/c$1 $current_blocks $current_date" blocks.log
                    tput sgr0
                else
                    printf "$warning" $coin_name $current_blocks $2
                    sleep 2
                    tput sgr0
                fi
            else
                printf "$normal" $coin_name $current_blocks $2
                tput sgr0
            fi

    else
            # $line as well as $1 and $2 remain set, will be used in next loop cycle
            if [ ! "$1" ]; then         # $1 is empty at EOF
                # create a new blocks.log to not disturb reading from original:
                cp blocks.log $$; mv $$ blocks.log
                echo "$coin_name $current_blocks $current_date" >>blocks.log
            else
                # insert before current line (address /$1/)
                sed -i '' "/$1/i$coin_name $current_blocks $current_date" blocks.log
            fi
    fi
) } > $i-runtime.log 2>&1 
done <blocks.log
```

The Important piece being similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693515/zsh-how-to-time-a-block-of-code) is the block of code I added two examples of above (not sure what groups you want to time or if individual commands.

```
{ time ( BLOCK; OF; MANY; COMMANDS; ) } > $i-runtime.log 2>&1
```

breaking this command down

- `{ time` creates a opens a block of code that we are going to time
- `(` creates the array of commands
- `BLOCK OF COMMANDS` self explanatory
- `)}` close up block
- `>` redirect to a file
- `$i-runtime.log` which file to place it in, youll want to have an environment variable or some useful name based on a block
- `2>&1` redirect STDOUT and STDERR, required to put the time output in a file.

As you probably know you could replace `>` with `>>` to save outputs from run to run in the same log file.

Comment: the idea here is to replace the line of `blocks.log` file if the `$current_blocks` are larger than the `$3` and `>>` will add new lines which is something not actually needed because we don't need the older logs if the condition I've mention met.

Answer (score 0):

> It just randomly deletes so I guess there's a conflict happening because of the reading/writing at the same time.

If the `sed` used there (a strange one, by the way, since it has the FreeBSD syntax `-i extension` with space after `-i`, not the Ubuntu GNU syntax `-i[SUFFIX]` without space) should indeed cause such conflicts, you can avoid them by reading from a copy of `blocks.log`, e. g.:

```
cp blocks.log blocks.old
for i in $wallets; do
    …
done <blocks.old
```

Then you can also remove the line `cp blocks.log $$; mv $$ blocks.log` - it's no longer needed.

---

> The problem is that the script doesn't return `$current_blocks` on every run. I don't know why but it is somehow missing it. It should've run this command `$i getblockcount` which will return a number. And it's running the command but not getting the number.

You'd have to decide what to do in this case; one possibility is to just skip this wallet in the current run, e. g. with this:

```
    if [ "$1" == "$coin_name" ]; then
        line='' # read new line next time
        if [ ! "$current_blocks" ]; then
            echo $i failed to return blockcount
            continue
        fi
        …
    else
        if [ ! "$current_blocks" ]; then
            echo $i failed to return blockcount
            continue
        fi
        …
```

Unfortunately we can't easily put the identical `if` blocks together outside the outer `if`, since the `line=''` has to be executed before we `continue`.

Comment: This still didn't solve the issue that you've quoted from my comment.

Comment: @Marry Jane - Then the reason must be different, since with this, there can be no more _reading/writing at the same time._ - Has a `-cli` file been removed from `/usr/local/bin/` between runs? (The script doesn't account for that.)

Comment: Well, it didn't actually. The problem is that the script doesn't return `$current_blocks` on every run. I don't know why but it is somehow missing it. It should've run this command `$i getblockcount` which will return a number. And it's running the command but not getting the number.

Comment: @Marry Jane - That's an important observation. I added a suggestion to the answer.