# zsh: setopt in function and make it stick

Tags: profiling, zsh

I'm trying to add profiling to my .zshrc inside of a function:

```
# via http://stackoverflow.com/a/4351664/329700
profile_startup() {
    PS4='+$(/usr/local/bin/gdate "+%s:%N") %N:%i> '
    echo "profiling away"
    typeset -g PS4='%D{%.} %N:%i> '
    exec 3>&2 2>$HOME/tmp/startlog.$$
    setopt xtrace prompt_subst
}
profile_startup
```

When I run it like this, /tmp/startlog is empty (nothing is logged). However when I run it outside of a function, in the bare zshrc:

```
PS4='+$(/usr/local/bin/gdate "+%s:%N") %N:%i> '
echo "profiling away"
typeset -g PS4='%D{%.} %N:%i> '
exec 3>&2 2>$HOME/tmp/startlog.$$
setopt xtrace prompt_subst
```

This adds lots of profiling data to the log.

Why isn't any log data recorded when I run the commands inside of a function? Is the setopt command not sticking? I tried adding `setopt no_local_options` to the end of the `profile_startup` command, and then only one log command was written to the file - the line adding `setopt no_local_options`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [zsh documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-LOCALOPTIONS):

> `LOCAL_OPTIONS <K>`
>
> If this option is set at the point of return from a shell function, most options (including this one) which were in force upon entry to the function are restored; options that are not restored are `PRIVILEGED` and `RESTRICTED`. **Otherwise, only this option, and the `LOCAL_LOOPS`, `XTRACE` and `PRINT_EXIT_VALUE` options are restored**.

There's a [clever way to work around this](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2014/msg00709.html):

```
profile_startup() {
    # do whatever ...
    trap 'setopt xtrace' EXIT
}
```