# Zsh cannot execute `set` command in a function inside .zshrc

Tags: configuration, zsh

Why can't Zsh execute `set` command in a function lives in ~.zshrc e.g.

```
tosettrace(){ [[ -o xtrace ]] || set -x; }
```

after `~.zshrc` is initialized

```
% tosettrace
```

has no affect on executing setting xtrace on

Please help solve to work

Comment: `set -x` doesn't seem to work inside a function; you might use an alias instead?

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27139530

Comment: @Fravadona: While I can reproduce the case, I believe that the explanation is more complicated. At least in scripting (non-interactive shells), a `set -x` in a function is propagated to the caller, and I have to do a `setopt localoptions xtrace` to restrict tracing to this function only. Perhaps an interactive shell behaves differently?

Comment: Aside from the interesting problem, I find the design for your function odd. It basically says _If trace is turned off, turn it on_. So no matter what the state of the trace was before, it will be turned on afterwards. Therefore, you don't need a guard, but can simply write `set -x` unconditionally. This would require much less typing than _tosetttrac_, and the function becomes a bit pointless. Perhaps you could use in your interactive shell an `alias sx="set -x"`, if you really want to save a few keystrokes.